# About NSPredicate in Core Data Fetch

Tags: iphone

I have two entities, User & Message.

- Message has a created_at timestamp;
- Message has a sender[to one relationship with User];
- User has a sentMessages[to many relationship with Message];

However I want to fetch all users who have sent any messages and with their latest sent message fetched together.

I've try fetch message and set predicate

```
created_at = sender.sentMessages.@max.created_at
```

but the compiler told me unable to parse sql statement?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is that exactly how you called it in your code? The @ operators are keyValue programming operators on collections, so you need to access them via key value semantics. Try:

```
created_at = [sender valueForKeyPath:@"sentMessages.@max.created_at"];
```

See

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE